# Resize to a specific width and height using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to generate thumbnails for videos, automatically. I cannot predict the format of the video, but I need the thumbnail to be 220x120 pixels, always. Using `-s 220x120` produces a weird stretch, just like `-vf "scale=220:120"`. I'd like the stretching to be uniform, either cutting away top and bottom if the video is too high or adding black borders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an example using a picture, same filter can be applied to video:

```sh
ow=220
oh=120
ffmpeg -i foo.png \
  -vf "scale=max($ow\,a*$oh):max($oh\,$ow/a),crop=$ow:$oh" bar.png
```

Regardless of aspect ratio, this will:

- scale down until width or height fits "the box"
- crop down the other until it fits as well

The commas inside needs to be escaped so they aren't interpreted as filter separators.

[§ Crop](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#crop)

[§ Scale](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#scale)